# Backbone.js templating example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I add a text box with label name age and view it in the template using backbone.js?

```
<label> Age</label>
<input type = "text" name = "age" value="12"/>
```

I want this to be added as an attribute to model and view it in template.  Can anyone help? I know the basics of backbone.js.

Comment: i got it cleared now am trying to create radio buttons

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want but here is the basic example:

```
var App = {};

App.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});
App.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#form",
    render: function() {
        var html = _.template($('#form-tpl').html(), this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});

$(function() {
    var person = new App.Person({
        name: 'Thomas',
        age: 37
    }),
    app = new App.View({model: person});
    app.render();
});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="form-tpl">
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" value="<%= age %>">
</script>
<div id="form"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CX3ud/

Also there are tons of tutorials available. Good luck!

Comment: <label>ModemControl:</label><input type="radio" name="modemcontrol" value="0" checked="checked"> off <input type="radio" name="modemcontrol" value="1"> on...how to add radio buttons as attributes to model and view it in a template..labels,textbox,dropdown too worked for me..dono to work with radio buttons..can u help me

Comment: i know wat d function toJSON()does?can u tel me wat it does here?

Comment: `toJSON` extracts attributes of the model so that it can be passed in template to render.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: i wan my template to look like Age://textbox//(this got worked)                        ModemControl://2 radiobuttons on n off//..now dis radio buttons shd be added as an attribute to model like age,then viewed in template.

Answer (score 1):

Templating isn't built-in to Backbone, which means you first have to pick a templating system.  There are many good options out there, but personally I prefer [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).  You could also choose from Mustache, the (very minimalist) Underscore template function, multiple jQuery plug-ins, etc.

Once you pick a library, you'll generally build/compile a template function with it to generate the HTML.  Here's a simple Handlebars example:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('<span>Hello {{target}}</span>');
```

That can (optionally) be done as part of your View code:

```
 var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
     template: Handlebars.compile('<span>Hello {{target}}</span>')
 });
```

Once you have that template function, you typically pass it a value map:

```
var resultText = template({target: 'World!'});
```

and get back the rendered result:

```
resultText == '<span>Hello World!</span>';
```

You can fit that in to Backbone however you want, but one common pattern is something like the following:

```
 var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
     template: Handlebars.compile('<span>Hello {{target}}</span>'),
     render: function() {
         var valueMap = this.model.toJSON();
         this.$el.html(this.template(valueMap));
     }
 });

 // Usage:
 new MyView({
     el: '#someElement',
     model: new Backbone.Model({target: 'World!'}
 )).render();
```

Comment: You're right that templates aren't built into backbonejs, but backbonejs has a hard dependency on underscorejs which does have templating built in.  http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: It does, but Underscore's templating capabilities are limited to a single, very minimal function.  If all you want to do is put variables in to strings `_.template` is great, but if you want to do the slightest bit of logic, even a single `if` conditional or `for` loop, which I consider necessary for any serious development, you need to consider other libraries (such as Handlebars).